# Place facebook login link

Tags: php, html, symfony

Using symfony2.1 and FosFacebookBundle.

I want to place a link on my homepage to login in facebook.

In my template:

```
<a href="https://www.facebook.com/dialog/oauth?client_id=APP_ID&redirect_uri=
           http://dev.example.com/auth/login&scope=email,read_stream" target="_self">
  test link login facebook</a>
```

If I click `test link login` facebook then I am still on my `dev.example.com/login?code=AQBgyy9u2qm...` site. When I copy the `https://...` link and put it in the address bar manual, everything works. How can I place it on my homepage, that the target is self, open up facebook, login and redirect to my homepage.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Let me get this straight, you are trying to test the oauth authentication dialog, and when you click the link, you are sent directly to your `redirect_uri` with a `code` parameter in the url?

I have some good news for you -- Facebook didn't bother showing the "Authorize this app?" page to you, since you have already authenticated the app.

To revoke those permissions, you'll have to enter your account's privacy settings, and revoke permissions to your app.

Comment: I used to logged in into facebook! Crap I really missed it! My fault! THANKS!

Comment: You're welcome -- sometimes it's the little oversights that *really* throw us for a loop...! Best to get a second pair of eyes on it, so you came to the right place.